# Solving linear recurrence relation problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, mathematica

Steve borrows 2500 dollars, at 12 percentage compounded monthly, to
buy a new 4k LED tv. If the loan is to be paid back over two years, what is his
monthly payment? Steve pays back the same amount every month.

I figured since it's monthly I divide the interest rate of 12% with 12 (12 months) which yields 1%.

a[0]=2500 as principal

a[n]=1.01*a[n-1]

a[n]=a[n-1]+0.01*a[n-1]

[I need to write it in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xLfd.png)

Comment: Are you familiar with the [amortization formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortization_calculator#The_formula)?

Comment: Yes I've seen it. I'm unsure how to write it as a linear recurrence relation. I'm trying to create a program in Mathematica that essentially yields the amortization formula.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$\Delta a(n)=1/100 a(n) \to a(n)= k(1+1/100)^n \to a(n)= 2500 (1+1/100)^n$

Comment: Yes, I yield the same answer when I compute it into an=r^n*a0. Input gives 1.01^24*2500=3174.3~.  If I compute it in (1-r^-n)/i I get the monthly payment. (1-1.01^-24)/0.01=117.7~.   I'm not sure how to write it as a linear recurrence relation. I'm trying to write it as a model in mathematica.